# Grid panel with textboxes

Tags: extjs, textfield

I need to create a grid with checkboxes and a textfield column, and when i push a button i want to get the data from each grid row textfield.

I have the grid with the checkboxs, i am missing the textfield part.

```
var grid = Ext.getCmp('prefix_grid');
var checkboxSelection = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
var v_url = 'GetBiddingRows.jsp';
var temp = '';
for (i=0; i<=checkboxSelection.length-1; i++){
    temp = temp + checkboxSelection[i].get('operator_desc') + ","
                  checkboxSelection[i].get('vendor_name') 
}
```

Comment: How are your columns defined?

Answer (score 0):

To add a textfield you either need to CellEditing or RowEditing which will require the user to click into the cell or row to show the text field: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing

Alternatively you can use the Component Column user extension: http://skirtlesden.com/ux/component-column